# Cannot see the database I create using MAMP

Tags: java, phpmyadmin, mamp

I wanted to use phpmyadmin to create database with tables using mysql through Java (netBeans). I downloaded phpmyadmin from this site http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php. then, I followed the instructions shown in this site: [steps of installing phpmyadmin](http://www.lynda.com/Apache-HTTP-Server-tutorials/Installing-phpMyAdmin-Mac-OS-X/77958/90527-4.html?vid=2&type=4) , but it doesn't work on my mac os.
I cannot open the start page of phpmyadmin.
After that, I installed MAMP from the Appstore and it works fine. But when I create database then go to phpmyadmin page, I cannot see my database, there is nothing ! and there is no errors in my code.
the database is established somewhere but I don't know where it is.

Does anyone knows whats going on? 
I think the phpmyadmin i first downloaded makes some conflicts to my java code.

any suggestions? solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give read/write permissions to your htdocs directory for users. You can try giving user/group/others access (it is **rw-rw-rw**) and you should go.

To do that right click on `htdocs`, click on Get Info, then take a look at the `everyone` group. Check you have read/write

[image]

Comment: My code works fine , it creates databases, but when I access phpmyadmin page to check the databases I don't find anything!   but when I try to create the same database again , a massage appears to me says your database is already exist !  The databases I created are saved and work properly in somewhere but not in phpmyadmin    @Fede